# Javascript flow union types missing property for redux action

Tags: javascript, redux, flowtype

I'm trying to learn how to use Flow but I'm stuck here.

I have a redux reducer that accepts different types of actions. The action payload is different for each action, for example:

```
const CreateNewTaskAction = (n: number) => {
    return {type: "CREATE", payload: n};
}

const AnotherAction = (r: TaskHandlerType) => {
    return {type: "WHATEVER", payload: r}
}
```

The types for action payload are like this:

```
type TaskHandlerType = {
    ...
    childId: number,
    parentId: number,
}                                                       


export type ActionType = {                                                       
    type: string,                                                                
    payload?: string | number | TaskHandlerType,
}
```

And this is part of my reducer:

```
const MyReducer = (state: StateType, action: ActionType) = {
    switch(action.type) {
        ...
        case "WHATEVER":
            ....
            var newChildrenArray = oldChildrenArray.filter((el) => {   
                return el != action.payload.childId;                   
            })                                                         
            ....

        }
    }
```

And this is the error that Flow spits:

```
Cannot get action.payload.childId because:
 • property childId is missing in String [1].
 • property childId is missing in undefined [2].
 • property childId is missing in Number [3].

              src/redux/reducers/tasksReducer.js
              57│             var oldChildrenArray = state[parentId].childrenIds
              58│             var elementIndex = oldChildrenArray.indexOf(action.payload)
              59│             var newChildrenArray = oldChildrenArray.filter((el) => {
              60│                 return el != action.payload.childId;
              61│             })
              62│             var newParentState = {
              63│                 ...state[parentId],

              src/redux/actions/actionType.js
 [1][2][3] 17│     payload?: string | number | TaskHandlerType ,
```

It is checking for the cases when the action payload is a string or a number and warns that those types doesnt have property childId, but thats why I use the switch statement, on that branch, action.payload will always have childId.

So how can I tell that to Flow?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of Flow are you using?

Comment: 0.75
+ 11 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: <s>I just noticed that your reducer is switching on `action.payload`. Maybe it should be switching on `action.type` instead?</s> OP commented that it was just a typo in the question.

Flow's having trouble deducing the type of `payload` since it cares primarily about the type of the `action` parameter (which indicates `payload?: string | number | TaskHandlerType`), rather than the specific shape of the value you're passing in.

The reason is: What would happen if you added *another* action with the same type but a different payload shape? This action might look like:

```js
{
  type: 'WHATEVER',
  payload: "foo"
}
```

and Flow wants to make sure your reducer will be able to handle it, since this action is valid according to `TaskHandlerType`. *You* wouldn't do this, of course, since Redux action `type`s have to be unique, but Flow doesn't know that.

Basically, there's an assumption – only one action can been defined with a particular `type`, and the shape of its `payload` will always be the same – which isn't visible to Flow. I don't *think* that Flow has any built-in capabilities to express this directly... but, fortunately, there's another way to solve the problem (albeit with more boilerplate).

You can use a [union type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/) (similar to `payload`'s type in `TaskHandlerType`) to tell Flow the exact shape of each particular message. One way to do this is like so:

```js
// Actions

type CreateNewTaskActionType = {| type: "CREATE", payload: number |};
const CreateNewTaskAction = (n: number): CreateNewTaskActionType => ({
    type: "CREATE",
    payload: n
});

type AnotherActionType = {| type: "WHATEVER", payload: TaskHandlerType |};
const AnotherAction = (r: TaskHandlerType): AnotherActionType => ({
    type: "WHATEVER",
    payload: r
});

// Types

type ActionType = CreateNewTaskActionType | AnotherActionType;
```

Now, Flow can know that a value with `type: "WHATEVER"` is guaranteed to have a `payload` type of `TaskHandlerType`.

[Interactive demo](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDCATngIYZ4ByeCAKmQM4DWAggMYYCWcAdnbgIBeMAG8APqjBhs+AFxgARIQBKAUVZ01igDRSwOMlnhkAJgt4BXALYAjPMVTiAvgG5U7PowxFSFarQMLBzcfGAiABS8Fjb2xACUCiTklDT0TGycPPyC4QB8YBGi+rJ4Csrqmtp60obGcGYWqM7x7pi5rLxwGAAWDiHZAvjhYpLSpeUA6gASVQBqaiq6+nUm5mBBzNNkvKYwDkN4Tm4eXj6d3X3EA2GRxAqb27v7xIeJYBe9-Vl8h-mFxXGgimsy0CyWNQMRjWCkcLTapQ2GSeewOuREEn07B6XBgpgAkusrHYHJDDKReBhCTESY4XAiOj8csMRMl-GlNjdeGBxB8ul9rkzDm1PLxvGAALJYFR4UyWdgOEYRMhMhRct7-QFgRgILgYbGFFWhXgAOlK8TE+mk7CYBAqGi0igUWuk0n2PgAHjS4iMjdkTasGqZ3K7XbY-MwQ67nFawDbGHaZvNFk7LaG3XhPd7FSI-XwA9CgybsbiCcHY9Jw+RI7GY9IY24gA)

Hope this helps, and please comment if you have any further questions!

Comment: Ok it makes sense, thanks.
The action.payload switch was a mistake copying it here, it is correct on the source code.